# Buenas tardes tengo un problema de novato usando Vue 3 en laravel

Tags: laravel, vue3

estoy tratando de crear un opcion de eliminar en laravel con vue3  pero creo mi apliacion despues mi componete , luego al incluirlo al mi templade de laravel , solo me muestra el input de eliminar en una sola opcion cuando debera de mostrarmelo en todas la opciones disponibles , espero su respuesta gracias

```
 <template>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger d-block w-100 mr-1" value="Eliminar x" 
 v-on:click="eliminarReceta">
</template>
<script>
    export default{
    methods: {
          eliminarReceta(){
            this.$swal({
                tittle: 'probando alerta',
                text: 'funciona bien',
                icon: 'success'
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>

al intentar recorre con foreach.

<tbody>
  @foreach ($recetas as $receta)
   <tr>
    <td>{{$receta->titulo}}</td>
      <td>{{ $receta->categoria->nombre}}</td>
      <td>
       <div id="EliminarReceta"></div>
 <a href="{{route('recetas/show', ['receta'=>$receta->id])}}" class="btn btn-success d-block mb-1">Ver</a>
 <a href="{{route('recetas/edit', ['receta'=>$receta->id])}}" class="btn btn-dark d-block mb-1">Editar</a>
                 </td>
              </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
         </tbody>

solo me muestra el input en la primera opcion , no en todas.
```

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FadSa.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder mostrar varios componentes tu código debería verse algo así, ya que debes iterar el componente y no el div

```
      <div id="EliminarReceta">
        @foreach ($recetas as $key => $receta)
         <eliminar-component :key="{{$key}}"><eliminar-component>
        @endforeach
      </div>
```